# NGX-Bootstrap: dropdown doesn't show the selected item

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I'd like to use ngx-angular dropdown. I've followed the installation instruction from [their official page](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/dropdowns). The dropdown is displaying, but when I select an item, it doesn't appear at the top like a regular dropdown.

I can't find any working example online. Even on their official page, when you select an item, nothing happens.

Can someone tell whether I need to add code to make it work?

## EDIT

1) Initial state

[image]

2) Expend and Select any item

[image]

3) Button Dropdown is still selected

[image]

Is this how it's supposed to work?

Comment: Can you paste an image to show the problem?

Comment: @DanielKucal, please see update.

Comment: @Richard77, yes that is how it works , please check , https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp and

Comment: Dropdowns are used to present e.g. some links like in the examples. I guess you want something like HTML `<select>` instead or `ng2-select` like Vivek said. Alternatively you can wrap the dropdown to implement value changes...

Comment: I guess my confusion comes from the fact that in ASP.NET webform everything is `dropdown`. Yes, I needed a select element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First what you are trying to implement is simple drop-down, That's not a select box , what you need is select box not drop-down.

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/dropdowns#nested

Q : I can't find any working example online. Even on their official page, when you select an item, nothing happens.

A : It's because, they just created a demo of drop-down as name suggests, you need to code on click event,

Here is the link of what you need (from same providers) :

https://valor-software.com/ng2-select/

---

Extra (if you need more) :

https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-plans